# How do I make an inline picture button using python aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

I tried a few things but while I'm able to display an inline button, I'm unable to get a picture button with a local icon stored in a folder within the script directory.
Any advice?

I've tried

```
import io
import os
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import InputFile, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.utils import executor


# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Create a bot object
bot = Bot(token=os.environ['BOT_TOKEN'])
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


# Handler for the /start command
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_handler(message: types.Message):
    # Load the image file and create a picture button
    with open('buttonPics/button_image.png', 'rb') as f:
        button_icon_data = io.BytesIO(f.read())
    button = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Click me!", callback_data="button_callback", )
    button.set_image(button_icon_data.getvalue())
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(button)

    # Send the message with the picture button
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=InputFile('buttonPics/button_image.png'), reply_markup=markup)


# Handler for the button callback
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda callback_query: callback_query.data == "button_callback")
async def button_callback_handler(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=callback_query.message.chat.id, text="You clicked the button!")


# Start the bot
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

The error I get is pretty clear: `AttributeError: 'InlineKeyboardButton' object has no attribute 'set_image'`

I've tried other examples I found but, I found nothing that displays a local picture inside a button. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the constructor

```
with open('buttonPics/button_image.png', 'rb') as f:
    button_icon_data = f.read()

button = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Click me!", callback_data="button_callback", icon=button_icon_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Unfortunately I still get the same AttributeError

Comment: scanning the documentation of aiogram, there is nowhere a parameter `icon` mentioned, which might have resulted in a similar (but I don't think "same") AttributeError.